# transforming 2 xml files from 1 xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have searched through the threads for similar posts, and though some are close, I'm having a difficult time understanding.

I need to transform 2 xml files from 1 xslt.  Here's what I have:

primary.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <bobo ID="123">
      <FirstName>Oscar</FirstName>
      <LastName>Bologna</LastName>
      <Address>1 Sandwich Street</Address>
      <City>Pickle Juice</City>
      <State>DE</State>
      <Zip>12345</Zip>
  </bobo>
  <bobo ID="124">
      <FirstName>Suzie</FirstName>
      <LastName>Que</LastName>
      <Address>1 Makeup Lane</Address>
      <City>Makeupville</City>
      <State>DE</State>
      <Zip>12346</Zip>
  </bobo>
</root>
```

secondary.xml - The value of the FKey element will have a matching value from the <bobo ID='xxx'> in the primary.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root>
  <bobo ID="789">
      <FKey>123</FKey>
      <HomePhone>(123) 456-7890</HomePhone>
      <MobilePhone>(123) 456-7899</MobilePhone>
      <Fax>(123) 456-7898</Fax>
  </bobo>
  <bobo ID="790">
      <FKey>124</FKey>
      <HomePhone>(123) 456-1234</HomePhone>
      <MobilePhone>(123) 456-1233</MobilePhone>
      <Fax>(123) 456-1235</Fax>
  </bobo>
</root>
```

Here's my feeble attempt at the xslt:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">

    <xsl:for-each select="root/bobo">
      <xsl:variable name="ID" select="@ID" />
      <xsl:variable name="xmlDoc" select="document('subfolder/secondary.xml')"/>

      <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/> <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="Address"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="City"/>, <xsl:value-of select="State"/>  <xsl:value-of select="Zip"/><br />

      <xsl:call-template name="Phones">
        <xsl:with-param name="FKey" select="$ID" />
      </xsl:call-template>

      </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="Phones" match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="root/bobo">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="FKey='$ID'">

          Ph. <xsl:value-of select="HomePhone"/><br />
          Cell <xsl:value-of select="MobilePhone"/><br />
          Fax <xsl:value-of select="Fax"/><br /><br />

        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

First, if I remove everything pertaining to secondary.xml in the xslt, the primary.xml gets transformed.  I'm confused on 1.) including the secondary.xml file.  Does it matter where this reference occurs within the xslt? 2.) I'm confused on how to pass the variable from primary.xml to secondary.xml.

I have read so many articles the past two days,... I'm more confused now than when I started.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How should your desired output XML look like?

Comment: The output is html and is just an address list.  As zx485 said below, it's not pretty but I can deal with that later.

Answer (score 0):

> including the secondary.xml file. Does it matter where this reference occurs within the xslt?

It can occur anywhere, even at the root level. But defining it in, e.g., a template restricts its usage to the corresponding scope (unless passed on with a parameter).

> The value of the FKey element will have a matching value from the  in the primary.xml file.

You can do this with a simple predicate expression. Here I chose

```
$secondXmlDoc/root/bobo[FKey=$ID]
```

which selects the `bobo` node from the secondary XML file which `FKey` value is identical to the `ID` variable.

> I'm confused on how to pass the variable from primary.xml to secondary.xml.

You don't. Both XML files are accessed from the same XSLT. But you forgot to add the `xsl:param...` with the line

```
<xsl:template name="Phones" match="/">
  <xsl:param name="FKey">
  ...
```

in the target template. BTW it's probably not a good idea to name a parameter the same as a node - it may create confusion.

---

As a whole, an XSLT-1.0 template could look like the following. I put the `document(...)` directive at the top level, so that you can access it from  anywhere in the XSLT file. And I removed the `call-template`, because it wasn't necessary. If you need it, make sure that you add an `xsl:param...` in the target template to receive a parameter (you didn't do this in the above code).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">
  <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="utf-8" omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
  <xsl:variable name="secondXmlDoc" select="document('subfolder/secondary.xml')"/>

  <xsl:template match="/root">
    <xsl:for-each select="bobo">
      <xsl:variable name="ID" select="@ID" />

      <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/> <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="Address"/><br />
      <xsl:value-of select="City"/>, <xsl:value-of select="State"/>  <xsl:value-of select="Zip"/><br />
      <xsl:variable name="secBobo" select="$secondXmlDoc/root/bobo[FKey=$ID]" />
      <xsl:if test="$secBobo">         <!-- Check if there is a matching entry in seconday.xml -->

          Ph. <xsl:value-of select="$secBobo/HomePhone"/><br />
          Cell <xsl:value-of select="$secBobo/MobilePhone"/><br />
          Fax <xsl:value-of select="$secBobo/Fax"/><br /><br />

      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is not pretty, but I guess you can easily take care of that yourself.

Comment: Many thanks zx485.  The changes to my mess worked great and I really do appreciate the explanations along the way.  When I first ran the changes, I got a xsltSettings (document()) exception, but found the fix here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xsl.xsltsettings.-ctor?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Xml_Xsl_XsltSettings__ctor_System_Boolean_System_Boolean_.  I didn't know (and forgive my my poor use of terminology) you could use a variable to basically house a node.  It's seems similar to passing an list object.  Very cool.  Thanks again!